# UIKIT Lightbox Javascript Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

Like many of you are aware, UIKit is simple and convenient for front-end development. One of its components , the lightbox ,can create astonishing modal boxes in a very simple way.
    
However , I cant find a way to satisfyingly close these modal box by using just JS. How is everybody closing these modal boxes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out ..

```
 var modal = UIkit.modal( '.uk-modal' );
    modal.hide();
```